# Autotext formatting in Mac MS Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm working with autotext in MS Word 2016 for my mac. I would like the autotext formatting to adjust to whatever formatting my current document is using. Scouring resources online led to me to toggle on the normally hidden paragraph markers when assigning the autotext, because apparently selecting these markers with your autotext will preserve the formatting.

Unfortunately, I've now highlighted the text I'd like to store as autotext both with and without the following paragraph marker and, no matter what I do, the formatting of the original text is preserved.

Anyone have any tips on this?

Comment: Do you mean "particular" when you said "particular a particular"?

Comment: nah i meant 'particular a particular' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found from [a thread](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=134553) that you should

1. Select the text you want to save.
2. Remove the formatting by pressing Ctrl-space.
3. Save it as a autotext / quick part / building block.

It worked flawlessly when I tested it in Word 2016. I saved the clean autotext, changed the default style font and pasted the autotext back. The pasted text was now in the default style.

Comment: My god. You are a genius. Thank you for this. :D